# parse a nested urlencode request body in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

How can I convert a urlencode request body (like one generated by PHP's [`http_build_query`](https://php.net/http_build_query) function), like this:

```
foo=bar&baz=3&metadata[name]=john&metadata[lastname]=smith
```

into a nested Python dict, like this?

```py
{
   'foo': 'bar',
   'baz': 3,
   'metadata': {
       'name': 'john',
       'lastname': 'smith'
   }
}
```

This looks like a common problem - so I'm sure that some libraries exist for this, it would be good to avoid writing own function for this. For example, [multidimensional_urlencode](https://github.com/uber/multidimensional_urlencode) solves the reverse problem - generating the query string from a dict - but does not do parsing.

Comment: How many nesting levels are you expecting in the input data?

Comment: Two or three, though I am sure a library solution will support arbitrary nesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [jQuery-Unparam](https://bitbucket.org/k_bx/jquery-unparam/overview) library:

```
from jquery_unparam import jquery_unparam

url = "foo=bar&baz=3&metadata[name]=john&metadata[lastname]=smith"
print(jquery_unparam(url))
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': '3', 'metadata': {'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'smith'}}
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks exactly like what I needed!